# Make a Boot Camp partition totally impenetrable?

Tags: macos, bootcamp, windows, partition

I'm thinking of setting up Boot Camp on my early 2011 MBP for gaming purposes because, obviously, VMs just don't cut it when they have to share their hardware with OS X. However, several forums I've read say that a Boot Camp partition could make the computer susceptible to malware that can somehow access the OS X partition. Short of using two separate drives, is there anything I can to totally isolate the partitions from each other, or otherwise keep the OS X partition totally safe?

[Some](https://discussions.apple.com/docs/DOC-3321) [links](https://discussions.apple.com/docs/DOC-3321) [about it.](http://ask.metafilter.com/84371/Windows-on-a-new-Mac-Safe)

Comment: Well if you wrote “everything I've read says that a Boot Camp partition could make the computer susceptible to malware that can somehow access the OS X partition” then it is a good idea to give at least some links about it.

Comment: @iskra Just edited it.

Comment: Any software residing on same hardware (hard drive) could find its way around, as you can access both partition so it can to. So thereis no absolute protection.

Comment: The only solution I can think of is using Xen or some other hypervisor -- the exact details about how to do it are rather complex and I wouldn't know if it would actually work on a mac. I suspect you would still have to have your windows installation on a separate drive though, so this might only be viable if you have more than one drive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your Mac OS partition is [encrypted with FileVault 2](http://support.apple.com/en-us/HT4790), it will be unreadable when you are booted to Windows. At that point, the only thing malware could do to this partition would be to wipe or delete it.

Answer (score 2):

The access to the OS X partition on Windows is managed through the HFS+ driver. If you uninstall it from Windows, the OS X partition will become inaccessible from Windows. It does virtually protect you from any kind of attack, unless a malware include itself the drivers (I hardly see that happening) or it simply deletes the whole partition. However, you won't be able to access any file in the OS X partition whilst using Windows if you uninstall the driver.

Unfortunately there is no other way. As stated in the previous answers, any piece of software running on a hardware has fully access to it, if no virtualisation is assumed.

Comment: Are there any negative side effects to uninstalling the HFS+ driver?

Comment: The only one I can think of is that you won't obviously be able to access the OS X partition from Windows, which will make impossible to browse through the files of OS X.

Comment: I clarified my answer.

Answer (score 1):

> a Boot Camp partition could make the computer susceptible to malware that can somehow access the OS X partition.

A better way to state this would be:

> Running Windows could make the computer susceptible to malware that can somehow access the OS X partition.

Any booted operating system on any partition has full control of any connected devices. The big advantage of a virtual machine is the rest of the computer does not exist as far as the virtualized part is concerned.

So, if you want to boot Windows on your Mac you are for all intents and purposes running a Windows machine with all it's vulnerabilities. But the hardware looks great.

Comment: I already knew that much. I was hoping someone could come up with a way (if a way is possible) to totally quarantine the Windows partition such that there's no way for any malware to creep into OS X. Basically, I'm torn between being a gamer and a germaphobe.